# H2 tag underline with bold and thin

Tags: html, css, border

i need help with CSS. I want to style h2 tag element underline.

Preview (what i need):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `:before` :pseudo-element to do this.

```css
h2 span {
  position: relative;
  color: #842990;
  font-weight: 100;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
h2 span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 35%;
  height: 5px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>QUICK NOTES</span></h2>
```

Comment: thanks... how :before pseudo is working ?